# What error code should I expect for user-cancellation of in-app purchases in mac-catalyst

Tags: in-app-purchase, mac-catalyst

I'm working on a catalyst app that isn't on the Mac App Store yet and when testing from Xcode or TestFlight cancelling in-app purchases gives me a [SKError.Code.unknown](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerror/code/unknown) instead of [.paymentCancelled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerror/code/paymentcancelled) that I get when cancelling on iOS.

Is it only the testing environment for mac-catalyst that doesn't report user cancellation correctly or will the app distributed from the Mac App Store also behave like this?